# Windows 10 Pro: Add PIN/Fingerprint fails

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-365, windows-10

i got some new Dell's (latest Win 10 pro 1903 fully patched) and want to enable PIN & Fingerprint for the new users.

All Users have Office 365 Pro Plus Emails.

Entering PIN or Fingerprint works fine, but when i want so save them i get the following Response:

[image]

[image]

and in the Event Log:

[image]

Its seems that Office365 is returning a WebForm instead an error/success code...

On my main Laptop everything is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: it looks for me that yozr request is malformed try at home without a vpn maybe thats a chance

Comment: I dont have a VPN. And the other maschines in the same network are working fine.